# What's a terminal similar to iTerm2?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line

My terminal choice has always been Guake, but at my job they have some Macs and I've started to use iTerm2 and I really love the split-functionality.

So I was searching for something similar in Ubuntu. I've tried with Guake + screen, but that is definitely not the same experience, because screen has to be executed as a command.

Yes, I could put it into my bash config, but if I split the screen I cannot move the scroll bar with the mouse (maybe there's a shortcut for this?). The other thing is that my bash config is completely screwed up with screen, I have a function to make an `ls` after each `cd` and another to show some info in my prompt when I enter a git repository.

Both don't work for me.

I really would like to know about a program with the iTerm2 functionalities for Ubuntu or, in the worst case, try to emulate them the most similar possible.

Comment: Terminator does almost everything you ask of it.

Comment: The problem with terminator (or at least I couldn't find it) is that doesn't have a global key to hide/show it as F12 in gnome

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-terminator-with-built-in-quake.html

Comment: ...but how the other question is a duplicate if this question is 3 months older?

Answer (score 18):

I also use/d iTerm2. After trying out tmux and Yakuake, I opted for [Terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator) and am very happy with it. Reason being, I didn't want a purely CLI-based multiplexer (tmux) ... I wanted more GUI based controls. And I didn't want a KDE based GUI (Yakuake). Terminator was the closest I found to iTerm2. The only feature I didn't find was the "clear" feature.

After deciding to switch and coming to post this answer, I noticed @[jrg](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg) said this also, as a comment. I posted this because I almost missed Terminator and don't want others to miss it.

- http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html
- https://launchpad.net/terminator

I became totally dependent on split-screens, and now my addiction can rage on:

**Simple layout example.**
[image: horizontal and vertical splits screens]

**Complex layout example.**
[image: very complex layout]

---

To install on Ubuntu or Mint, search for `Terminator` in *Software Center* ( *Software Manager* on Mint )... or open *Terminal* and type:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

---

So far, the only feature I have not found is the ability to right-click on a session screen, and have a "clear" option to purge the buffer of visible text in that session.

Comment: Not sure that I'm understanding the feature 'clear', that your are missing. But perhaps try typing "CTRL + L".

Comment: @SteffenChristensen I mean that in iTerm2 there is a context menu option labeled "Clear" ... which when clicked purges the scrollback buffer. It's like typing `clear` into a terminal, except you cannot scroll back. With `clear` the command, versus `Clear` the Context Menu option, I notice the buffer remains there, it's just pushed out of view. With the `Clear` context menu option, the scroll back is fresh as if you opened a new terminal, except you don't lose your window/screen-segment position and state in the session.

Comment: Does it has the "Profiles" like Iterm2? I rely on them to setup my SSH access shortcuts and apply actions like theming for prod/staging servers, would be awesome if had compatible profiles.

Comment: @Vadorequest yes it does. If you save the profiles you can launch them with desktop shortcuts no problem, but obviously also CLI invocations. Putting together arrangements like that takes so much time, it would be very discouraging to remake them every time ( but I do remake them every time anyway for some reason )

Answer (score 9):

Even on the mac, I am using [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)! :)

[image: split]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://tmux.github.io/ss-tmux3.png))</sub>

To install:

```
apt-get install tmux
```

Comment: @Till Have you ever used iterm2?

Answer (score 3):

My choice of terminal is [Yakuake](https://yakuake.kde.org). It has both vertical and horizontal functionality and more:

[image: Yakuake with multiple splits]

### Installation

```
sudo apt-get install yakuake
```

Comment: I have removed the `yum` command. This command may be right on other systems, but we are on Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu doesn't have this command.